# ratingBar.getTag() returning null

Tags: android, android-listview, ratingbar

I am making an android app in eclipse. My app has a list which contains RatingBar in a ListView. I am using custom ArrayAdapter to display list. Below is my code .... it throws a nullpointerexception at statement ratingBar.getTag(); I can't figure out why?

```
public class MyChoicesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyChoice> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private ArrayList<MyChoice> myChoicesList;

private static final String TAG = "MyChoiceAdapter";
private Context c;

public MyChoicesAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
        ArrayList<MyChoice> myChoicesList) {
    super(ctx, viewResourceId, myChoicesList);
    c=ctx;
    this.myChoicesList = new ArrayList<MyChoice>();
    this.myChoicesList.addAll(myChoicesList);

}

private class ViewHolder
{
  TextView name;
  CheckBox cb;
  RatingBar rb;
  TextView naText;
  TextView gotItText;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(position));

    if (convertView == null)
    {

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_choices_row, null);

      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_choices_row_text);
      holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_choices_row_checkBox);
      holder.rb = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_choices_row_rating);
      holder.naText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_choices_row_na_text);
      holder.gotItText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_choices_row_got_text);

      convertView.setTag(holder);

      holder.cb.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
      {

         public void onClick(View v)  
         {
             CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
             MyChoice _choice = (MyChoice) cb.getTag();
             _choice.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
         }
      });

      holder.rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
            boolean fromUser) {

             RatingBar rb = ratingBar;
             if(rb == null)
                Log.v(TAG, "rb is null");
             if(rb.getTag()==null)
                Log.v(TAG, "rb.getTag() is null");
             MyChoice _choice = (MyChoice)rb.getTag();
             _choice.setRating(rating);
             Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(rating));
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    MyChoice choice = myChoicesList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(choice.getName());
    holder.cb.setChecked(choice.isSelected());
    if(choice.getNA().equalsIgnoreCase("N/A"))
        holder.naText.setText(choice.getNA());
    if(choice.getGotIt().equalsIgnoreCase("Got it!"))
    holder.gotItText.setText(choice.getGotIt());

    holder.rb.setRating(choice.getRating());
    holder.rb.setTag(choice);
    holder.cb.setTag(choice);


    return convertView;

}

  }
```

Here is part of the logcat

07-02 06:58:31.330: V/MyChoiceAdapter(989): rb.getTag() is null
07-02 06:58:31.330: D/AndroidRuntime(989): Shutting down VM
07-02 06:58:31.330: W/dalvikvm(989): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.cybergeniesolutions.scentsysquirrel.MyChoicesAdapter$2.onRatingChanged(MyChoicesAdapter.java:89)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.RatingBar.dispatchRatingChange(RatingBar.java:318)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.RatingBar.onProgressRefresh(RatingBar.java:261)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:660)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:672)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBar.java:719)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBar.java:700)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.RatingBar.setRating(RatingBar.java:197)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.cybergeniesolutions.scentsysquirrel.MyChoicesAdapter.getView(MyChoicesAdapter.java:107)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-02 06:58:31.440: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: There is no statement ratingbar.getTag() in your code. I see twice rb.getTag() and cb,getTag() and convertView.getTag(); Does all work for cb?

Comment: yes all is working fine for cb.

Comment: `There is no statement ratingbar.getTag() in your code`

Comment: Why are you posting that same piece of code again? And this time unreadable while not formatted?

Comment: ok I have edited my question and made MyChoice _choice = (MyChoice)rb.getTag(); statement bold.

Comment: I prefer you make ratingbar.getTag() bold. And reread carefully what i posted.

Comment: OK its done ratingBar.getTag() is a part of a statement, its value is being assigned to MyChoice object.

Comment: If that statement really causes a NullPointerException - which i doubt-  then ratingBar has to be null; Check for that and if null do not excecute that code but display a Toast saying so. And it is time you post the LogCat with the errors and stacktrace as i think ratingBar is not null and your exception is elsewhere.

Comment: I already did that ratingBar is not null. Its really weird, can't figure this out.

Comment: No. In the code you posted earlier you checked (rb.getTag()==null). That is too late. You have to check like if (ratingBar==null).

Comment: I did that too, it was not null so I deleted that code.

Comment: IT IS TIME YOU POST THE LOGCAT

Comment: I have added the logcat in my question.

Comment: Looking at the logcat it looks as if the null pointer exception occurs during getView(). Until now I always supposed that it only happened when the user changed the rating. Can you elaborate?

Comment: exception occurs at the start of the activity or should I say activity never starts.

Comment: If you had told that right away.... So the `onRatingChanged` will be invoked already when you set it in getView() with `holder.rb.setRating(choice.getRating());`. Please take that line out for a test to see if my idea is correct. Further add again the checks for null pointers to `onRatingChanged`. And if you find a null then do not execute following code but return. (In your earlier code you checked for null but then continued). Please update the code here too.

Comment: yes, your idea is correct if I take out holder.rb.setRating(choice.getRating()); from my code there is no null pointers, but removing this I lose the state of my view.

Comment: Thanks for your help...My code is running perfectly now. I have moved holder.rb.setRating(choice.getRating()); statement after holder.rb.setTag(choice);